# Solver/Goal Seek without changing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have a sheet with a bunch of small formulas in it that wind up bouncing into each other before outputting a total at the end.

Using Goal Seek or Solver I can select the Output Cell (C50), the Input Cell (C4), and then set the Answer to 0, and it'll plug in the Solution (2.14 with current setup) in C4.  This is vastly preferred to reverse engineering all the formulas as it takes some time and they will be changed fairly frequently.

All of this is correct and fine, except I do NOT want to change C4 when it's done, but rather output the answer in another cell(C54).  Ideally I was trying to create a function I could throw in C54 that would display the Solution, but so far I can only get it to evaluate as "False" or I get value errors depending on what I've tried.

Instead I wound up with this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cOriginal As Currency

    cOriginal = Cells(4, 3).Value
    SolverOk SetCell:="C50", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="C4", Engine:= _
        1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
    Cells(54, 3) = Cells(4, 3).Value
    Cells(4, 3) = cOriginal
End Sub
```

Now this will work and I can flesh it out with variables as needed, but it seems pretty inelegant and I was wondering if there were a smoother way to do this rather than literally just loading the original value and then swapping stuff out.

Oh and I should mention that I can't just let it change C4 and then mirror the change in C54, as the whole point is to leave cell C4 as somewhere we can plug in test values to see how things change, while knowing what the "Break Even" value is by glancing at C54.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly inelegant about your solution (other than the `(True)`, which should be just `True`)

Comment: Darn.  I was hoping I could somehow get it into a UDF, but I don't see a way to do that with my current code

Comment: Because Solver is updating the Excel environment, you won't be able to use a UDF.

Comment: Just to be thorough, there is no way to get solver or goal seek to find the solution without updating the excel environment?

Comment: Solver works by changing a cell (`ByChange`).  If it isn't allowed to do that, it can't evaluate your formulas with the changed value in order to iterate toward the solution it is looking for.